# Questions about a pivot

Tags: assassins-creed-3

I did the tutorial for the pivots and got my first 3 pivots.

But if you plant a pivot and another player finds it, what happens to the pivot? Do you lose it forever? Do you have to find it again? Does it change locations?

I am a bit worried that I might lose the pivots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are putting your pivots in the map noone will be able to take them.Only you are able to take them back through the map.When you find the pivot that you are looking for just be sure to pick up all the pivots that you placed so you can use them again.They doesn't change locations and you will not lose them.